# WebFlux hook composed but not executed

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I try to understand WebFlux behavior regarding hooks execution and there is something I don't get. So I have defined this hook:

```
        Schedulers.onScheduleHook("hook",
                                  hookToDecorate -> {
                                      log.info("composing {}", hookToDecorate);
                                      return () -> {
                                          log.info("running {}", hookToDecorate);
                                          hookToDecorate.run();
                                      };
                                  });
```

And here is the flow I execute:

```
        Mono.just("Testing onSchedulerHook")
            .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
            .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .block();
```

The ouput is the following:

```
main 2020-04-17 21:25:16.863 [] INFO  ---    c.b.t.p.c.w.WebfluxConfigurationTest:45  : composing reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable@6736fa8d
main 2020-04-17 21:25:16.869 [] INFO  ---    c.b.t.p.c.w.WebfluxConfigurationTest:45  : composing reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber@1c852c0f
elastic-2 2020-04-17 21:25:16.871 [] INFO  ---    c.b.t.p.c.w.WebfluxConfigurationTest:47  : running reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber@1c852c0f
```

I would like to understand why the result of the first composition is never called. Indeed, I had the hope that I could rely on such strategy in order to pass a thread local variable from one thread to another during the execution of a flow (I know we are not supposed to do that but let's pretend I don't have a choice), a bit like this (the code has been simplified):

```
        Schedulers.onScheduleHook("hook",
                                  hookToDecorate -> {
                                      var value = fetchThreadLocalValue();
                                      try {
                                          return () -> {
                                              registerAsThreadLocal(value);
                                              hookToDecorate.run();
                                          };
                                      } finally {
                                          clearThreadLocalValue();
                                      }
                                  });
```

But it doesn't work: during the first composition the *try/finally* block is executed but the lambda that is supposed to register the value in a thread local is not, so we lose the value on the way...

Any insight will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am no guru at hooks but after reading the documentation i belive this is your problem.

The docs docs for `onScheduledHooks` States the following:

> The sub-hook is a Function taking the scheduled Runnable. It returns
>   the decorated Runnable.

Meaning that the supplied function takes in the former function, and then you add your stuff to it and return a new function.

```
return (lastFunction) -> {
    // Get values from last function and decorate with you stuff ontop
}
```

But if you just want to pass values from thread to thread you should instead use the reactive context. It was built for the purpose of just this, passing thread local values.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context